# Android remote image in listview - what to do if missing?

Tags: android, image, listview, image-processing

I'm working on app that reads remote XML with this structure:

```
<items>
    <item>
        <id>ID</id>
        <title>TITLE</title>
        <img_url>http://URL</img_url>
    </item>
</items>
```

I'm parsing this XML and feed the listview with the data from XML. When an image URL is provided I load the image from remote URL, it works fine.

Problems are:

- how to find out that there is no image at that URL to prevent application from failure when trying to load not existing image?
- how to load some default image when no image URL is provided?

To explain: it happened recently that there was no image at URL provided in XML, so my Android app failed to load it and it was force closed (yes, I then put it into try-catch but I'd rather show a default "no image" image instead). There can be items with no image URL and in that case I'd like to show some default "no image" image. But how to process local image file when my custom ArrayAdapter is expecting an URL for image to be downloaded?

My app life cycle is as follows:

1. start activity is a listview
2. it calls GetItems method that loads the XML, parses it and fill in the custom ArrayAdapter
3. in the GetView method of AA the drawable bitmap from image URL is loaded in the ImageView - so I suppose here all the problem should be fixed - check for the url, it is provided check for the loaded image, of it is loaded then show it; if no url or no image loaded, load default image...

I know the algorithm, what I'm looking for is some (working) code example...

Many thanks for any advice...

Comment: I wrote that I used try catch, but it only leads to no force close... What I need is to load some default image instead of broken URL or no URL provided... Sometimes I think that people do not read...

Comment: I think some people use try -catch only for handling exceptions and left catch block blank. But in that "catch" part you can write your code which you want to do. Just assign default image to your ImageView in that catch block.

Comment: OK, I did handle the case when NO URL is provided. This was pretty simple in final, but still have to handle the case when no image found where it should be regarding to URL provided in XML feed. But OK, I missed the option of doing something else then logging of exception message in catch part - so I'll try to catch exception when no image could be found and instead return image from local resources within catch... Thanks!

Comment: @SaurabhPareek returned after some time. Please, write Your comments leading to the solution in the answer so I can accept it. TIA!

Comment: @SaurabhPareek Please, rewrite Your comment into an answer so I can accept it. Thank You!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use try-catch for handling exceptions and write your code to assign default image to your ImageView in catch Block.